# Function for onclick=" " in <a></a> tag won't work - what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to disable a link depending on certain conditions.  For now, I have just been messing around with the script/html to see how everything works together.

I found out that the following code *does not* work and I am not sure why-

HTML:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{attachment.url}}" class="btn btn-link">{{attachment.name}}</a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.agreementPermission = function() {
    return false;
};
```

This seems like the conventional way of disabling an href, but for some reason the link is still clickable and it opens the page.

The following *does* work:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{attachment.url}}" onclick="return false" class="btn btn-link">{{attachment.name}}</a>
```

Maybe this would be easier -- I'm wondering how I could configure the entity 'attachment.url' so that I could just reference the href to some function like so:

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript: agreementPermission()" onclick="return agreementPermission()" class="btn btn-link">{{attachment.name}}</a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.agreementPermission = function() {
     if (someCondition) 
       open {{attachment.url}}; //I know this is not correct/allowed
}
```

What am I missing? Any further suggestions? Thank you SO community!

Comment: Are You using angular?, If so, you should use ng-click, not on click

Comment: Yes I am. I will make that a tag.

Comment: Why not use a button,and just open the page with js?

Comment: You should also be using the javascript way of adding an event to a dom element. the tags, from what I've seen, don't always work.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight it must be a link.

Comment: `agreementPermission()` is a property on `$scope` it is not a globally defined function

Comment: @PatrickEvans how can I make it globally defined?

Comment: You cannot use onclick with returning a value. Basically you can call the function and return the value that you want within the function itself.

Comment: @FatihAktepe this also does not work: 
    <a target="_blank" href="{{attachment.url}}" onclick="agreementPermission()" class="btn btn-link">{{attachment.name}}</a>

Comment: Since you are using angular you don't, you use angular's ng-click directive like The Dark Knight suggested instead of onclick

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  I'm going to look up on that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-href` to only include the URL when needed:

```
<a target="_blank" 
   ng-href="{{someCondition ? attachment.url : ''}}" 
   class="btn btn-link">{{attachment.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to disable the url with a certain condition. Why don't you use ng-disabled? For example;

in HTML;

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{attachment.url}}" ng-disabled="condition" onclick="someFunction()" class="btn btn-link">{{attachment.name}}</a>
```

in JS;

```
    $scope.condition = false;
    $scope.someFunction = function(){
        if(condition){
          open {{attachment.url}}
        }else{
          $scope.condition = true;
        }
    }
```